# Aging formula without using additional column

Tags: excel-formula, countif

I have a table like below

```
ID  StarDate    EndDate
123 6/5/2015 15:54  6/12/2015 15:54
124 6/6/2015 15:54  6/8/2015 15:54
125 6/7/2015 15:54  6/9/2015 15:54
126 6/8/2015 15:54  6/11/2015 15:54
127 6/9/2015 15:54  6/15/2015 15:54
```

I want to get the total count of aging without using any additional column
0-30    =COUNTIFS(A:A,">124",A:A,"<127",TODAY()-B2:B6,"<=30")

The one above is not working
Please help achieving this.

Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your table starts in cell A1, with the first start date in cell B2, try

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(C2:C6-B2:B6<=30))
```

Edit after clarification:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A6>124),--(A2:A6<127),--(TODAY()-B2:B6<=30))
```

Comment: I added a different formula

Comment: If I give entire column, B:B it give me  #VALUE result. Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't use whole columns with Sumproduct. Contain the range. You can use dynamic range names that grow and shrink with the data.

Comment: The #Value error in Sumproduct means that the referred ranges are not the same size.